# How to compare spoken audio against reference recording - language learning

Tags: linux, audio, machine-learning, audio-processing

I am looking for a way to compare a user submitted audio recording against a reference recording for comparison in order to give someone a grade or percentage for language learning.

I realize that this is a very un-scientific way of doing things and is more than a gimmick than anything.

My first thoughts are some sort of audio fingerprinting, or waveform comparison.

Any ideas where I should be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means a trivial problem to solve, though there is an abundance of research on the topic.  Presently the most successful forms of machine learning in the speech recognition domain apply [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) techniques.

You may also want to take a look at existing implementations of HMM algorithms.  One such library in its early stages is [ghmm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghmm/).

Perhaps even better and more readily applicable to your problem is [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to chomp's great answer, one important keyword you probably need to look up is Dynamic Time Warping (DTW). This is the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping